# Index.html files – must these be present in every directory?

Tags: security

In addition to [question about blank **index.html** files](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/347/why-does-a-joomla-distribution-still-contain-index-html-in-each-folder) I would like to know:

- if the webserver is not configured properly, is it still a *must* to have **index.html** (empty or not) in every directory? For example extension directory **media/com_akeeba/js/** is missing the file.
- is there a verification tool to check whether all directories have **index.html** present?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From a technical aspect, index.html files are not required, but do prevent directory access on badly configured environments as already noted.

If you're looking to list an extension on the Joomla! Extensions Directory, (JED) it is not required to have index.html files; this change was made somewhere around March 2013.

You can use the JEDChecker extension at http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/miscellaneous/development/21336 to check JED requirements including the index.html file.

If you want to add index.html files to your site, you can copy the script at https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/build/indexmaker.php and run it from a command line session on your server.

Comment: Totally agree with @Michael. :) If you want to create index.html without command line then you can prefer this script https://gist.github.com/mManishTrivedi/5531498

Comment: Since he/she specifically asked about the media folder, it should be noted that the media folder typically has restrictions for public access via the htaccess on a properly configured server.